# how to use java regex convert query list sql into query count sql

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want remove the `order by` in sql, and convert

`select a,b,c from` into `select count(*) from`

---

`select uid, uname from user order by uid`

**=>**

`select count(*)  from user`

---

`select uid, (select depname from department t01 where t02.depid = t01.depid ) from user t02 order by uid`

**=>**

`select count(*) from user t02`

---

`select uid, '('||uname||')' from user`

**=>**

`select count(*) from user`

---

`select uid from (select uid,rownum as row_num from user order by uid) where row_num < 10 order by uname`

**=>**

`select count(*) from (select uid,rownum as row_num from user order by uid) where row_num < 10`

---

how to use java regex do that?

`select uid, uname from user order by`
hibernate can convert it into page query `select uid, uname from user order by limit xxxx` automaticly, execute it we can get a list.

then if we execute `select count(*) from user`, we will get count of user.

`pageNo`, `pageSize` is set by myself, `pageNum` is `record_count/pageSize`. I hope get all data of `table/grid` by one sql, but I dont know how to convert query list sql into query count sql.

Comment: Silly question .. why regex ? Order by will be the last statement of a sql query , you can literally find the position or order by and remove the string with `str.substring`

Comment: it's not sure how many spaces between `order` and `by`

Comment: That doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming order by is at the end, you could use

```
query = query
 .replaceFirst("(?is)\\sorder\\s+by\\s.*$","");
 .replaceFirst("(?is)^\\s*select\\s.*?from\\s","select count(*) from ");
```

BUT, it's not really appropriate. Analysing a SQL query requires grammar parsing which is out of scope of regexes. The example I gave would fail on

```
select ... from ... where title = 'I want to order by my cat'
```

Which is a simple counter example, but you can imagine *much* more complex SQL queries.

Comment: +1 but this will probably fail on the last query where order by is part of the subquery (which doesn't make sense imho)